# Copying/pasting geometry in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, geometry

I am currently in the process of qualifying some polygon data in QGIS. Specifically, I have to ensure polygons from layer 1 follow the edges of the polygons in layer 2. Sometimes, copying the geometry of a polygon from layer 2 is more useful than manually editing the polygon in layer 1.

This is where my question arises; is there anyway to update the geometry of a polygon in layer 1 to match that of a polygon in layer 2? I want to keep my original data, only updating the geometry.

I am manually editing a polygon layer in QGIS, so no automation is necessary. I am the only one involved in the project.

The other polygon layer I have consists of smaller polygons that should be combined to form polygons for the other layer, whilst preserving the attributes of the original layer.

Hope this makes sense.

I can also work in PostGIS, if that makes my problem easier to solve.

I have tried the using St_Snap and Topology Checker, however I have not been able to solve my issue using these.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the process? Is it all manual or also automated? Only by you or also other (less involved) people? Taking a geometry from one table/layer into the other is not the problem, it is more difficult to decide when you want to do that and make it user-friendly.

Comment: I am manually editing a polygon layer in QGIS, so no automation is necessary. I am the only one involved in the project. 

The other polygon layer I have consists of smaller polygons that should be combined to form polygons for the other layer, while preserving the attributes of the original layer. 

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I think your work can be best done in postgis, but to give advice on that it would be better when you can add some images of what exactly you are trying to achieve. Even better when you can share some example data.

Comment: This seems to be the same question I'm asking here:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/178870/63457

I'd still be interested in finding answers for this; while I did get a number of elaborate methods for achieving it, it seems that it should be possible as almost a one-click operation.

Answer (score 2):

You can view, copy and paste the feature geometry in WKT using the Plain Geometry Editor plugin, without changing the underlying attributes. You can replace the geometry of a feature from one layer with that from another, create rings within an existing polygon using the geometry of another polygon, and so forth.